# Como le puedo pasar un parámetro desde un select u otro a un "c:forEach"

Tags: java, sql, jsp, foreach, taglib

estoy desarrollando una interface para el kardex, para ello quiero mostrar los datos con una sentencia SQL, pero necesito pasarle un parámetro (NombredelProducto), ya he probado con ${NombredelProducto}, 'NombredelProducto', "NombredelProducto". Pero no tengo resultados, alguno a tenido esta experiencia y me pueda comentar alguna idea de como solucionarlo, quiero usar las etiquetas para acortar código. Gracias

Actualmente con la sentencia de abajo, me trae el producto que le indico ahi mismo, sin embargo le intento pasar un parámetro y no tengo resultado

```
*Etiquetas*

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
*Consulta*

<sql:query var="sqlingreso" dataSource="jdbc/sowad">
select T3.fecha_ingreso,T3.almacen,T3.id_ingreso,T1.id_producto,T2.des_producto,T4.nom_marca,T5.nom_mod,T1.cantidad_ingreso,T1.stock_producto
    from detalle_ingreso T1
    inner join producto T2 on T2.id_producto = T1.id_producto
    inner join ingresop T3 on T3.id_ingreso = T1.id_ingreso
    inner join marca T4 on T4.id_marca=T2.id_marca
    inner join modelo T5 on T5.id_modelo=T2.id_modelo
    where T1.id_producto='1';
</sql:query>

*Aqui completo los datos en una tabla*

<c:forEach var="i" items="${sqlingreso.rows}">
<tr>
<td>${i.fecha_ingreso}</td>
<td>INGRESO</td>
<td>${i.id_ingreso}</td>
<td>${i.cantidad_ingreso}</td>
<td></td>
<td>${i.stock_producto+i.cantidad_ingreso}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

==============================================================
: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:591)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Answer (score 2):

Antes de nada me gustaría comentar que:

- JSP hoy día se considera algo casi obsoleto.
- usar sentencias SQL en un JSP es una muy mala práctica. Te aconsejo usar un patrón MVC y que tu JSP reciba los datos ya "preparados" y sólo se preocupe de mostrarlos.

Dicho esto, lo que necesitas es `<sql:param />`:

```
<sql:query var="sqlingreso" dataSource="jdbc/sowad">
select T3.fecha_ingreso,T3.almacen,T3.id_ingreso,T1.id_producto,T2.des_producto,T4.nom_marca,T5.nom_mod,T1.cantidad_ingreso,T1.stock_producto
    from detalle_ingreso T1
    inner join producto T2 on T2.id_producto = T1.id_producto
    inner join ingresop T3 on T3.id_ingreso = T1.id_ingreso
    inner join marca T4 on T4.id_marca=T2.id_marca
    inner join modelo T5 on T5.id_modelo=T2.id_modelo
    where T1.id_producto = ?;
    <sql:param value = "${NombredelProducto}"/>
</sql:query>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, te comento que lamentablemente no tengo exito, este es el error que me sale:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
    select T3.fecha_ingreso,T3.almacen,T3.id_ingreso,T1.id_producto,T2.des_producto,T4.nom_marca....
    from detalle_ingreso T1
    inner join producto T2 on T2.id_producto = T1.id_producto
    inner join ingresop T3 on T3.id_ingreso = T1.id_ingreso
    inner join marca T4 on T4.id_marca=T2.id_marca
    inner join modelo T5 on T5.id_modelo=T2.id_modelo
    where T1.id_producto='?';

Comment: ¿Podrías poner todo el stack trace de la excepción en la pregunta?

Comment: He quitado las comillas al ? que indica el parámetro, prueba así

Comment: Si, le quite las comillas al ?, si me funcionar si le declaro una numero, pero al momento de pasarle el parametro con "${txtCodigoPr}" no llega, ese txtCodigoPr lo traido del id de un input el cual en primera instancia lo lleno con una funcion de onclick en un for:each, no logro encontrar la forma de enviar dicho value a la consulta sql:query

Comment: Si le pasas un String cuando espera un Integer, por ejemplo, es normal que te falle